# Simple window in swing JAVA

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

Task: make the same window as in the screenshot below using JAVA swing:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWiFq.png]

What did I do:

- Created a panel for the top block (BorderLayout), added two more panels to it (GridLayour), one for the left buttons(FR, FG, FB), the other for the right buttons (A, B,C), added it all to my JFrame window
- Created a JScrollPane and added it to the JFrame too
- Created a panel for the bottom block (BorderLayout), added two more panels to it (GridLayour), one for the left buttons(1,2,3,4...), the other for the JTextFiel text field, added it all to my JFrame window.

The result is below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqoH5.png]

I tried using other layouts, but it still doesn't work. I attach the code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyJFrame extends JFrame {

    JPanel pan1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel pan2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel pan3 = new JPanel();
    JPanel pan4 = new JPanel();
    JPanel pan5 = new JPanel();
    JPanel pan6 = new JPanel();

    JButton jButton1 = new JButton("FR");
    JButton jButton2 = new JButton("FG");
    JButton jButton3 = new JButton("FB");
    JButton jButton4 = new JButton("A");
    JButton jButton5 = new JButton("B");
    JButton jButton6 = new JButton("C");

    public MyJFrame(){

        super("Simple Swing App");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocation(650,300);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
        setResizable(true);



        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

        jButton1.setBackground(Color.red);
        jButton2.setBackground(Color.green);
        jButton3.setBackground(Color.blue);

        pan1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3,2,2));
        pan2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3,2,2));
        pan3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pan4.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,2,2));
        pan5.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1,1,1));
        pan6.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        pan1.add(jButton1);
        pan1.add(jButton2);
        pan1.add(jButton3);

        pan2.add(jButton4);
        pan2.add(jButton5);
        pan2.add(jButton6);

        pan3.add(pan1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        pan3.add(pan2, BorderLayout.EAST);

        for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
            JButton jButton = new JButton(i+"");
            pan4.add(jButton);
        }

        for (int i=1; i<4; i++){
            JTextField jTextField = new JTextField(" Pole tekstowe " + i + " typu jTextField ");
            jTextField.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            jTextField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.CYAN));
            pan5.add(jTextField);
        }

        pan6.add(pan4, BorderLayout.WEST);
        pan6.add(pan5, BorderLayout.EAST);

        add(pan3);
        add(scrollPane);
        add(pan6);



        setSize(700,450);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I can guess the question, but since I don't like guessing, what *is* the question?

Comment: (1+) You have the correct approach in using nested panels with different layout managers. You just need to solve the problem one step at a time. Don't use a GridLayout as the main layout. That makes every panel the same height. Keep the default `BorderLayout` of the frame. Then add child panels to the `PAGE_START`, `CENTER` and `PAGE_END`.  See: [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). Once the top level layout is what your want, move on to the child panels. It becomes an iterative process.

Comment: @camickr *"Once the top level layout is what your want, move on to the child panels"* Huh .. I actually go the other way. Starting with the smallest sections of the GUI which make sense to be represented as a single panel / layout, I then work outwards to positioning those in larger panels with different layouts. There's more than one way to skin this cat!

Comment: @AndrewThompson *I actually go the other way.* - to each his own. The key is to realize that you can use nested panels with different layout managers, which the OP seems to be doing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is *"How to make this GUI?"* I would use this approach:

- 3 x `BorderLayout` (**red**) - one for the entire GUI, one each for the `PAGE_START` and `PAGE_END` constraints of the main GUI panel.
- In the panel used in the `PAGE_START`, 2 x `FlowLayout` (**green**), one in the `LINE_START`, the other in the `LINE_END`. (1)
- In the panel in the `PAGE_END`, 2 x `GridLayout` (**blue**), the first a 3 x 3, the other a single column.

[image]

1. If the components at the top (the groups of buttons on the left & right) need to be the exact same size, also use grid layouts for them.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you helped me a lot. Only one question remains: the text field at the bottom right does not change its size when the window is resized. Is it possible to somehow ensure that the text field also changes its size?